# Convert 2d tensor to 3d for use in LSTM layers

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm building a small program to predict some float from an 1d array of floats. So far I've been using `dense` layers to achieve this:

```
const model = sequential();
model.add(layers.dense({units: 32, inputShape: [numCols,]}));
model.add(layers.activation({activation: 'relu'}));
model.add(layers.dense({units: 4}));
model.add(layers.dense({units: 1}));
```

Where my `xs` input shape is `[numRows, numCols]` (e.g. `[132, 100]` - in a dataset of 132 examples: [[1, 2, 3, ...], [4, 5, 6, ...], ...]) and my `ys` output is a single value `[num]` (e.g. `[17.50]`).

But I wanted to try out LSTM to test if it would perform better. The issue is that the layers for LSTM want a 3d matrix and I was not sure how to go about it.

I've tried the following:

```
const trainXs = xs.clone()
  .reshape([numRows, numCols, 1]);
```

The above converted my input `[[1, 2, 3, ...], [4, 5, 6, ...], ...]` to `[[[1], [2], [3], ...], [[4], [5], [6], ...], ...]`.

And the layers:

```
const model = sequential();
model.add(layers.simpleRNN({
  units: 32,
  inputShape: [numCols, numRows], // [100, 132]
  recurrentInitializer: 'glorotNormal',
  returnSequences: true
}));
model.add(layers.simpleRNN({
  units: 32,
  recurrentInitializer: 'glorotNormal',
  returnSequences: true
}));
```

But the above would fail with the following error:

```
Error: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_SimpleRNN1_input to have shape [,100,132], but got array with shape [132,100,1].
```

I'm a bit confused and I'm not sure how I should reshape my 2d tensor to fit the requirements of the LSTM layers.

**Update**:

The fit call:

```
model.fit(trainXs, trainYs, {
  epochs: 1000,
  batchSize: 12,
  validationData: [testXs, testYs] // Test data has the same shape as trainXs/trainYs
});
```

I only have a single layer the moment:

```
model.add(layers.simpleRNN({
  units: 32,
  inputShape: [1, numCols, numRows],
  recurrentInitializer: 'glorotNormal',
  returnSequences: true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference says:

> The shape of the input (not including the first, batch dimension) needs to be at least 2-D, with the first dimension being time steps.

so the first dimension of your input should contain the time steps. For simplicity just use 1. So in your case the shape of the tensor, which is passed to the cell would be `[1, numCols, numRows]` as you already got in the error message.

Comment: That results in a different error: `Error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer simple_rnn_SimpleRNN1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4`.

Comment: You misunderstood me, the `inputShape` in the layer still is `[numCols, numRows]`, but the shape of trainXs should be `[1, numCols, numRows]`

Comment: I just noticed `tf.layers.simpleRNN` doesn't even have an `inputshape` option, the result is always `[batchSize, sequenceLength, units]`

Comment: Ok. So I reshape `xs.reshape([1, numRows, numCols]);` and leave `inputShape` for the layer as is. That throws: `Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense1 to have 3 dimension(s). but got array with shape 132,1`. But you're saying to reshape `[1, numCols, numRows]`, how do I do that?

Comment: The order of cols and rows isn't the problem I think, I was just confused about your example which mixed it up. Just sticking to one order will work, but if you really want to switch it, `transpose()` is the method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171415/discussion-between-sebastian-speitel-and-roland).